# crash when calling library

Tags: c++

Let's hope I can dumb this down without leaving out crucial details...

I've got a test program:

```
#include <lib.h>

const char * INPUT  = "xyz";

int main()
{
    initializeLib();
    LibProcess * process = createLibProcess();
    fprintf( stderr, "Before run(%s)\n", INPUT );
    process->run(INPUT);
    fprintf( stderr, "After run(%s)\n", INPUT );
    return 0;
}
```

This test program I compile (gcc 4.1.2) and run as:

```
g++ -g -o test test.c -L /path/to/lib -I /path/to/include -lnameoflib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/lib
./test
```

The library is rather complex, and not-too-smart in some places, and most importantly not-written-by-me, so don't flame me for the architecture of the functions involved:

```
class ProcessBase
{
    public:
        virtual int run( const char* buffer = NULL ) = 0;
}

class LibProcess : ProcessBase
{
    public:
        LibProcess()
        {
            fprintf( "Reached LibProcess().\n" );
        }

        int  run( const char* buffer = NULL )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "Reached run().\n" );
        }
};            

void initializeLib()
{
    // Preparing some data
}

ProcessBase * createLibProcess()
{
    ProcessBase * process = new LibProcess();
    fprintf( stderr, "Created Process.\n" );
    return (ProcessBase *) process;
}
```

So far, so good. But the output of it really had me baffled:

```
Reached LibProcess().
Created Process.
Before run(xyz)

SEGFAULT
```

I know the error is (most likely) somewhere completely different. But *how is this at all possible?*

I would understand if the test died on calling the library the first time. I would understand if the test died when creating the process, or when it actually *does* something in run().

*But how can it die **between the calling of the function and actually reaching that function?***

I'm clueless, especially I don't know how to continue debugging this. Help?

**Edit:** Yes, I checked process to have a non-NULL value after createLibProcess(). A subsequent call to two different member functions of process, left out of the example, also worked beautifully. But the second member function call trashed memory due to a buffer overflow, and zeroed process.

This makes the question invalid. *Of course* is calling NULL->run() a segfaulting offense.

Question can be closed as "no longer relevant". Thanks anyway!

Comment: Tough one.  Is the code you posted really the one that is executed, or is there a major simplification for the sake of illustration?  If this is more or less what is actually executed, set a break-point before jumping into the run method.  Check whether the vfptr-table is corrupted.  Check whether the arguments are correctly passed.  No further idea, at first.  Well, also run the program under valgrind, and let it do the usual memory-checks.

Comment: Left-field suggestion/question - are you sure that there isn't a #define for INPUT somewhere that blats your definition?

Comment: @ Timo: No such define anywhere. @ gimpf: Of course many things are left out - the functions shown have parameters in reality (except for run(), which is called exactly as shown), and some effectively-no-op code is left out. (Checking of return values, status messages etc. which all report back OK until run() crashes.) I'll check vfptr / valgrind, and then report back.

Comment: Is this question now closed are is there still an unresolved issue?

Comment: The question was invalid from the start - process == NULL at the point of the function call. (Due to a buffer overflow I've already fixed in the meantime.) Question can be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is process definitely set to a non-NULL valid pointer before it is dereferenced to call run?

Answer (score 3):

If:

```
LibProcess * process = createLibProcess();
```

returns NULL, or a process that is invalid in some way, you will get exactly the behaviour you are seeing.

Comment: process is valid - in the attempt to keep the example readable, I did cut away a process member function (process->configure()) that is successfully (!!) called before process->run().